# Using string matching from csv to find patterns in Python using results from OCR

Tags: python, flask, python-tesseract

I am new to python and I want to use the results from the OCR (string) to be able to match the first column of my csv file and then only if the condition is true (the string from ocr matches to the one in the csv then it should use the pic. I get an error as soon as I try to integrate the code together.

For the OCR, I am using pytesseract and I am using Flask to render the web app.

**The error I get is** : AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'filename'

**New error:**  The view function for 'upload_image' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

**This error only persists when I try to add this code:**

```
    match = extracted_text
    matched_row = None
    with open("/Users/ri/Desktop/DPL/DPL.csv", "r") as file:
        # Read file as a CSV delimited by tabs.
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == match:
                matched_row = row
                print(matched_row)
```

**app.py**

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # checks whether or not the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd() +
                                   UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER, file.filename))

            flash('File successfully uploaded')

            # calls the ocr_processing function to perform text extraction
            extracted_text = ocr_processing(file)
            print(extracted_text)

            match = extracted_text
            matched_row = None
            with open("/Users/ri/Desktop/DPL/DPL.csv", "r") as f:
                # Read file as a CSV delimited by tabs.
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
                for row in reader:
                    if row[0] == match:
                        matched_row = row
                        print(matched_row)

                        loaded_vec = CountVectorizer(
                            vocabulary=pickle.load(open("./tfidf_vector.pkl", "rb")))
                        loaded_tfidf = pickle.load(open("./tfidf_transformer.pkl", "rb"))
                        model_pattern_type = pickle.load(
                            open("./clf_svm_Pattern_Category.pkl", "rb"))
                        model_pattern_category = pickle.load(
                            open("./clf_svm_Pattern_Type.pkl", "rb"))
                        match = [match]
                        X_new_counts = loaded_vec.transform(
                            match)
                        # .values.astype('U')
                        X_new_tfidf = loaded_tfidf.transform(X_new_counts)

                        predicted_pattern_type = model_pattern_type.predict(X_new_tfidf)
                        your_predicted_pattern_type = predicted_pattern_type[0]

                        predicted_pattern_category = model_pattern_category.predict(
                            X_new_tfidf)
                        your_predicted_pattern_category = predicted_pattern_category[0]
                        return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                                               msg='Processed successfully!',
                                               match=match,
                                               your_predicted_pattern_category=your_predicted_pattern_category,
                                               your_predicted_pattern_type=your_predicted_pattern_type,
                                               img_src=UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER + file.filename)
                        # break
                    else:
                        print("no mattern found")


        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect(request.url)
```

Comment: You've overwritten your `file` variable when you use the context manager to open your file. Try a different variable name with this line `with open(...) as file` e.g.  `with open(...) as f`.

Comment: I have made changes to the code as per your suggestion, and re-added the code. The new code error is:  The view function for 'upload_image' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. @PGHE

Comment: This is solved! The return statement was also missing! Thank you for your help @PGHE